# Here is my final code. I am getting in the end the error message multiple times and I don´t know why

Tags: java

I am getting in the end the error message multiple times and I don´t know why. Can you please explain me why and maybe help me find the solution to fix it?

```js
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayListUserDefinedObjectExample { // defining class
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();   // setting arraylist
        users.add(new User("David", "Pot" , 17, "male", "Armstrong Str. 24", "Griesheim, 57401", "Hessen")); // getting info of the given student
        users.add(new User("John","Lok", 20, "male", "Madison Str. 76", "Darmstadt, 19050", "Hessen"));  // getting info of the given student
        users.add(new User("Daniel","Wild", 15, "male", "Gartner Str. 39", "Darmstadt, 34012", "Hessen")); // getting info of the given student
        users.add(new User("Martin","Mill", 19, "male", "Willow Str. 12", "Offenbach, 45012", "Hessen")); // getting info of the given student
        users.add(new User("Jake","Mill", 19, "male", "Willow Str. 12", "Offenbach, 45012", "Hessen"));  // getting info of the given student

        System.out.println("EKS administration");
  System.out.println("----------------------------------");

  users.remove(3); // removing object at the given index
  users.add(2,new User("Logan","Paul", 18, "male", "Maximilian Str. 90", "Offenbach, 45012", "Hessen" )); // adding student at the given index

        User u = new User();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the student that you are looking for: "); // user enters the student name
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        u.setName(scanner.nextLine()); // the machine is searching all the names for the right one
        
        for (User user : users){
            if (u.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(user.getName())){
                System.out.println("The name of the student is " + user.getName() +"\n" + user.getLastname()+ " and this student is " + user.getAge() +" years old" + "."+ "This student is a " + user.getSex() + "." + "\n" +"House adress of this student:" + user.getStreet()+ "\n"+ "City and postcode:"+ user.getPlace()+ "\n"+ "State:"+ user.getState());
            } // user gets all the info for the student that he searched 
            
            
            else { 
             
             System.out.println("----------------------------------"); 
             System.err.println("You gave a wrong name");
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe you have mis-tagged this question as javascript instead of java.

Comment: What is your specific problem? please describe what you are trying to achieve and in what way your results differ from the desired result. Also try and be specific with problems "I don't know how to do this" isn't specific enough

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry about the tag , So what I am trying to do is that in the beginning the program ask : ''Please enter a name'' and then I am entering for example Daniel, then the program has to to show me all the info about him, his name and his age. That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: Try investigating the `.stream().filter()` method on your `List<User>`, I think you'll find it operates similar to your `forEach()` call, but lets you (as the name suggests) _filter_ the elements.

Comment: If you want the user to input the name you should look into the `Scanner` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the code below.
So first thing I would add is an empty constructor, so you can create an object without data.
Then by the help of the scanner the code will wait for you to enter first name (press enter). For each will iterate over your list and compare the names. When there is a hit it will return that object.

```
class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public User(){}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public class ArrayListUserDefinedObjectExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(new User("David", 31));
        users.add(new User("John", 24));
        users.add(new User("Daniel", 15));


        User u = new User();
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        u.setName(scanner.nextLine());

        for (User user : users){
            if (u.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(user.getName())){
                System.out.println("Your name is " + user.getName() + " and your age is " + user.getAge() +".");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but what I want is to get the information about the people that are in the code, for example the program will ask in the beginning ''Please enter a name'' and then I will enter Daniel and then the program will show me '' Daniel, 15 years old'' . Thanks though.

Comment: Aha, so you want to enter a name and search the records by the name then return that object?

Comment: Basically yeah.

Comment: I will try it and I will let you know. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: How does accepting an answer work? for more information https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hey there, I just finished my code. Everything works great except of the else statement that I added. I am getting the error message multiple times and I don´t know why.